# What is the "correct" way to determine how many forum post/comments happened in a month

Tags: nodes

I have a drupal advacned forum where I need to track the number of posts.  I was using the node number but now believe this is wrong.  What is the preferred/correct way to count the posts (both new topics and comments) in a given month?

Comment: There is not one single "correct" way, but you are correct in thinking that the node ID is not, because it could give incorrect data.

Comment: Is there a way that will work?  My boss really wants these numbers.

Comment: Do you need to display the numbers on your website or just get the numbers for reporting?

Comment: There is the core Statistics module and a host of contrib statistics modules as well. A simple aggregated view filtering on post date range and counting on content type will also do the trick.